# What is the appropriate syntax for assigning every index to nullptr while the array is of type STL container

Tags: c++, syntax

Ive got this constructor here in which I have to set these buckets to nullptr

```
template<class T>SetType<T>::SetType() {
    // Create an array of forward_lists and initially set to an empty forward_list 
    buckets = new forward_list<T>[DEFAULT_BUCKETS];
       // buckets = nullptr;
    for (int i = 0; i < DEFAULT_BUCKETS; i++)
    {
        buckets[i] = nullptr;
    }
}
```

This is how the variable "buckets" is declared in the header file

```
private:
    forward_list<T>* buckets; // An array of forward_list's
                                // (each index is a foward_list)
```

[image]

Comment: `std::fill` comes to mind.

Comment: or `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<forward_list<T>>> buckets;`

Comment: I would think abot using `std::vector<std::forward_list<T>> buckets;`.